# How to add ajax cart counter in custom navigation?

Tags: ajax, woocommerce, header, navigation, cart

I'm building a website with Elementor, and I've implemented my own header and navigation bar through HTML and CSS. The only problem is - I don't have a cart icon with quantity and AJAX, that is opening a sliding cart on a click.

Is it possible to add something like that on the store? I'm currently using the Cart plugin, but I can't paste it on the header. It just floats through the screen.

Any ideas how I could build this inside my navigation?

Cart plug in, several function files.

Don't have any

Answer (score 0):

Create a place to put these cart content in your header :

```
global $woocommerce;
$woocommerce->cart;
```

You'll get all things have been added to cart as an object array and get what you want

Comment: It's not working.

I would like cart icon to appear in navigation menu, and then on click to swide in from right. Ajax has to be included to it automatically updates the cart without refreshing the page.